# No attribute "target" in ChEMBL Database

Tags: python, macos, module, attributeerror

I'm new for programming so I need help. As you in picture, although I installed chembl_webresource_client (pip3 install chembl_webresource_client), I couldn't work "target" module. Please help me!

By the way, My python version is Python 3.10.2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Zzz.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows you that there is no method called target in new_client and only a method called client_from_url inside new_client.py, and you may mean the same thing and want to use it.

And I suggest you share your chembl_webresource_client version.

that is last release of chembl_webresource_client == 0.10.7

Comment: thank you for answer and the version of chembl_webresource_client I am using is 0.10.7. This codes have operated in colab so I ask for it.